# How to login to a website, read data?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to write a GoogleApps script that accesses a website, logins using my credentials, makes a selection from a drop down menu and copies the displayed values to paste them on my active spreadsheet.

Is this possible or should I go about it a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Directly, that is not possible. However if the website offers an API or if the website makes use of URL parameters to pass information about what you've selected, it *might* be possible if the website also uses HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible.  Capture what you need to do for authentication.  Repeat it with Google Apps script.
Capture what you need to do with the drop downs.  Repeat it with Google Apps script.

Quite generic instructions, but you didn't give any more specificity to your problem.  Use something like TamperData addon for Firefox to capture/see what Google Apps Script needs to pass back and forth to the server.

Comment: Thank you. This is promoising.